# sqlite db usage in iphone app giving errors

Tags: sqlite

I am creating an app with user login using sqlite i am storing the login details which includes the users favorite movies.suppose another user who has downloaded the app also picks the same movie i want to be able to let the other 1st know about 2nd user.how do i do that.does the sqlite db used to store login details be available for the other user or should i have server to upload each user's login details?I think my confusion is stemming from the fact that i dont understand how people use sqlite in iphone app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very rare instances SQLLite should be used directly. The best way to handle data storage local to an iOS device is `CORE DATA`. I would suggest you consider using Core Data for storage and not call or mess with SQL Lite directly.

Comment: thanks for the reply.ok say i use coredata that is still a framework. my question is more from the point of view how to access the data of one user by another..is it through a central storage ?

Comment: That would be best accomplished IMHO with using a server like SQL Server or MySQL. You can have it check everytime a movie is requested if anyone else (who meets a certain criteria) access that same movie, it sends them a message. SQL Lite and CoreData are only local to the device so you need something common between the users.